# multiple forms run at server make visible to client asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, css

i have made registeration form, forgot password and login form in a single aspx page . I am using css to style the whole form. I am using 3 form tags. Here is code:

**ASMX**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" visible="true">
<ul>
<li>
   <asp:TextBox ID="email" runat="server" TextMode="email" placeholder="Email" OnTextChanged="email_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="email" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator">*Requied</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

</li>
<li>
                       <asp:TextBox ID="password"  runat="server" TextMode="Password" placeholder="Password" OnTextChanged="password_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="password" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator">*Requied</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                    </li>
<li>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />

 </li>
<li>
    <asp:Label ID="Invalid" runat="server" Text="Invalid  Username or Password" Visible="False" ></asp:Label>
     <asp:Label ID="Try" runat="server" Text="You  can't  try again ,Register Your Self" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
</li>


</ul>
</form>

  <form runat="server" id="form2" visible="false">  

               <ul>
                    <li>

  <asp:TextBox ID="username" runat="server" MaxLength="15" placeholder="UserName" OnTextChanged="username_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="username" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ForeColor="Red">*Please Input user name</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
   <asp:Label ID="userchk" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
  </li>
                    <li>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="EmailR"  runat="server" placeholder="Email (must be valid)" OnTextChanged="EmailR_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>

                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" runat="server" ControlToValidate="EmailR" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ForeColor="Red">*Please Input email</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="EmailR" Display="Dynamic" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" ErrorMessage="RegularExpressionValidator" ForeColor="Red">Input Valid Email</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="FirstName" runat="server" placeholder="FirstName" MaxLength="15" OnTextChanged="FirstName_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>

                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator8" runat="server" ControlToValidate="FirstName" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ForeColor="Red">*Please Input first name</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
           <asp:Label ID="chkemail" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label> 
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="LastName" runat="server" placeholder="Lastname" MaxLength="15" OnTextChanged="TextBox3_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>

                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="LastName" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ForeColor="Red">*Please Input Last name</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>


                    </li>
                    <li>
  <asp:TextBox ID="Pass" runat="server" placeholder="Password" TextMode="Password" MaxLength="15" OnTextChanged="Pass_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>

                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Pass" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ForeColor="Red">*Please Input password</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                    </li>
                    <li>
               <asp:TextBox ID="Cpass" runat="server" placeholder="Confirm Password" TextMode="Password" MaxLength="15" OnTextChanged="Cpass_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>


                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator7" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Cpass" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ForeColor="Red">*Please Enter the Confirm Password  </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

 </ul>                 
  </form> 

        <form runat="server" visible="false" id="form3">
            <ul>
                <li>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="SendEmail" runat="server"  TextMode="Email" placeholder="Enter Email" OnTextChanged="SendEmail_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator11" runat="server" ControlToValidate="SendEmail" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator">*Requied</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                </li>

                <li>
                    <asp:Button runat="server" text="Send email" OnClick="SendMail_Click" CssClass="button" Visible="true"   CausesValidation="False"/>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <asp:Label ID="ml" runat="server" Text="Email sended Sucessfully" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                   <asp:Label ID="ml0" runat="server" Text="Email Didn't Match " Visible="False"></asp:Label>

                </li>
                </ul>

               </form>
```

I used following Js in toglling categories:
     **JS**

```
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#list1").click(function () {
            $("#form1").fadeIn("slow");
            $("#form2").css("display", "none");
            $("#form3").css("display", "none");
        });
        $("#list2").click(function () {
            $("#form2").fadeIn("slow");
            $("#form2").css("visible", "true");
            $("#form1").css("display", "none");
            $("#form3").css("display", "none");
        });
        $("#list3").click(function () {
            $("#form3").fadeIn("slow");
            $("#form3").css("visible", "true");
            $("#form2").css("display", "none");
            $("#form1").css("display", "none");
        });
    });
</script>
```

and here is my css [FORMS](http://jsfiddle.net/ab7omjnp/2/)
I have to use multiple forms in any case .. can anyone help please??

Comment: Help with what? What is the question?

Comment: how to make other form content visible true? when i toggle those form id?

Comment: Your markup and CSS are making this nearly impossible to fix. You're adding a hide class to some of the form's parents. You can show the form, but it isn't overriding the parent's class. If you can clean up some of the nesting and get rid of the hide class you'll be headed in the right direction.

Comment: `<form runat="server" id="form2" visible="false">` is it necessary to make this `visible` attribute true?? using jquery or javascript

Comment: No, you do not need that.

Comment: any other alternative??

Comment: Clean up your markup and CSS. Let CSS handle the visibility of your forms.

Comment: i have done this using css but now i am unable to access functions behind page